# Hibernate, search by primary key returns all from table

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have this issue with Hibernate that when i try to retrieve unique result using criteria hibernate returns all the content from the table.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
Customer c = new Customer();
c.setCustId(custId);
Example ex = Example.create(c);
Criteria criteria = HibernateUtil.getSession().createCriteria(Customer.class);
criteria.add(ex);

Customer customer = (Customer)criteria.uniqueResult();

HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
HibernateUtil.closeSession();
```

However querying the table with:

```
Customer customer = (Customer)session
                    .createSQLQuery("select * from customer_ where custid = :id")
                    .addEntity(Customer.class)
                    .setInteger("id", custId)
                    .uniqueResult();
```

returns correct entry.
`custId` is the table's primary key. And the `Customer` class contains 2 `@OneToMany` mappings.

Do I need to add something to the criteria example above??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples) says:

> Version properties, **identifiers** and associations are ignored.

(emphasis mine)

Why not simply using `Session.get()` if you have the identifier?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did not realize that i can use session.get(). I was just following an example. So identifier == primary key?? and associations == annotated fields?? Is it not strange that i cant use them with criteria search?? Sorry for stupid questions, its my first time using hibernate.

Comment: associations = OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne, and ManyToMany. An association with another entity.